# App-Scoped vs. Document-Scoped Security-Scoped Bookmarks

Tags: macos, appstore-sandbox, security-scoped-bookmarks

Quick Question:

I'm working on a document based application in OS X.  Can I use an App-Scope bookmark to gain access to a file, or must it be a document-scope bookmark?

I understand that any app can use both of these, but I wasn't sure if perhaps the app-scope bookmark can't be accessed by a specific document of that app.

I initially implemented an app-based scope bookmark and when I attempt to startAccessing it, it always returns FALSE.

Wondering if I will need to change this to a Document-scope to get it to work.

Here's a link to my other question which shows the actual code:

[Security Scoped Bookmark - startAccessing always returns FALSE and Resolved URL doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586796/security-scoped-bookmark-startaccessing-always-returns-false-and-resolved-url)

Thanks!